Waveshare IT8951 power consumption
Waveshare has an IT8951 EPD controller board used in connection with a lot of their high resolution e-ink displays. I can't find any information about the board's power consumption in the Waveshare documentation, nor does the IT8951 datasheet (I have only been able to find a preliminary edition) say anything about the chip's power consumption.
Does anyone have one of these displays in use and know how much power the controller draws? When searching for information, I only found a few forum entries seeming to indicate that the Waveshare controller consumes a significant amount of power, which if true, makes it unusable for my purposes.

Which particular Waveshare board are you interested in? 1200x825, 9.7inch E-Ink display HAT for Raspberry Pi which says uses a IT8951 controller is given Total refresh power and Total standby power values in the Specifications section.

@ChesterGillon Most probably the 7.8" version, but I would assume that the standby power consumption of the IT8951 is independent of the display. For the 7.8" version, Waveshare mentions a standby power of 0,1W which is much lower than the alleged standby power for the combination with other display sizes and does not match well with what I have read elsewhere about the IT8951 standy power consumption: https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/e-paper/epaper-1/7.8inch-e-paper-hat.htm
